Como se puede mandar correo phpMailer desde GoDaddy
$mail   =   new PHPMailer(true);
$response = array(
    'success' => false,
    'message' => '',
    'debug' => ''
);
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->smtpConnect(['ssl' => ['verify_peer' => false,'verify_peer_name' => false,'allow_self_signed' => true]]);
try {
    $mail->SMTPDebug     = 3;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host          =    'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth      =    true;
    $mail->Username      =    'chinosf@gmail.com'; // Tu dirección de correo Gmail
    $mail->Password      =    base64_decode($base); // Tu contraseña de Gmail
    $mail->SMTPSecure    =    'tls';
    $mail->Port          =    587; // Puerto SMTP para Gmail (TLS)
    $mail->setFrom('chinosf@gmail.com', 'Odasaf'); // quien envia
    $mail->addAddress('chinosf@gmail.com', 'Odasafhhhhhh'); // a donde llega
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject       =    $_POST['subject'];
    $mail->Body          =    "Tienes un mensaje del correo ".$_POST['email']." con el nombre de ".
    $_POST['name']." el mensaje del correo dice lo siguiente ". $_POST['message']." para que contacte con la persona";
    ob_start();
    $mail->send();
    $debugOutput = ob_get_clean();
    $response['success']  = true;
    $response['message']  = 'Message has been sent';
    $response['debug']    = $debugOutput;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $response['success'] = false;
    $response['message'] = "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    $response['debug'] = ob_get_clean();
}
echo json_encode($response);

es el que utilizo en goDaddy para tratar e enviar correos desde un formulario pero no me lo permite de hecho ni error sale solo no llega al correo.
Tambien se trato de enviar por medio de mail() pero tampoco funciona no se si es por estar bloquedas o falta algun elementos para ser enviado

Hola. ¿Qué muestra exactamente json_encode($response);? ¿Has verificado en la carpeta Spam del correo?

solo muestra Correo enviado exitosamente.
Debug Info:  , asi como sale vacio de hecho si estan carpeta spam se busca y no sale nada, eso es en goDaddy pero desde otros servidores web el codigo anterior si funciona

¿Podrías intentar adaptar tu código a este ejemplo en el repositorio oficial? Supongo que además tu versión de PHPMailer está actualizada.

es la ultima version de hecho ayer lo descargue del repositorio oficial de igual voy a probar ese ejemplo a ver que tal
